# Django forms dynamic dropdown list creation

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

## models.py

## Create your models here.

```
class DeviceType(models.Model):
    device_type = models.CharField(max_length=200,unique=True)

class Repair(models.Model):
    device_type                     = models.ForeignKey(DeviceType,to_field='device_type')
    submitted_by                    = models.ForeignKey(User,to_field='username')
    comments                        = models.TextField()
    repair_request_date             = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
    repair_status                   = models.ForeignKey(RepairStatus, to_field="repair_status", null=True)
    repair_cost_estimate            = models.FloatField(null=True)
```

## views.py

```
def repair_form(request):
    dlist = get_my_choices(request.user)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RepairForm(request.POST,device_type = dlist, submitted_by = request.user)
        #print(form)
        if form.is_valid():
            print("Inside repair form")
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.submitted_by = request.user
            print(post.pk)
            post.save()
            return redirect("RepairRequest")
    else:
        dlist = get_my_choices(request.user)
        print("Inside else of repair form")
        form = RepairForm( device_type = dlist, submitted_by = request.user)
        print("else form: ", form)
        return render(request, "Form_template.html", {"form": form,\
                                                      "name": "Repair Request Form"})
```

## forms.py

```
class RepairForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("kwargs: ",kwargs)
        dlist = kwargs["device_type"]
        print("Inside init of RequestForm")
        super(RepairForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["device_type"] = forms.ChoiceField(choice = [dlist])
        self.fields["submitted_by"] = kwargs["submitted_by"]



    class Meta:
        print("Inside Meta of RepairForm")
        model = Repair
        print("model: ", model)
        fields = "__all__"
        print("fields: ", fields)
        exclude = ("repair_cost_estimate","repair_status","submitted_by","repair_request_date",)
```

I am trying to create a dynamic dropdown list in django forms. Dynamic in the sense that the dropdown list will only populate with the data that is associated with the given user. In my case, each user may have a laptop, mouse, etc. with him. I have written the code shown above. Every time I execute the code I get the following error:

```
TypeError at /user_dashboard/RepairRequest.html
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'submitted_by'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/user_dashboard/RepairRequest.html
Django Version: 1.11.13
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'submitted_by'
Exception Location: E:\inventory management\inventory_management_service\inventory_management_app\forms.py in __init__, line 15
Python Executable:  C:\Anaconda2\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.14
Python Path:    
['E:\\inventory management\\inventory_management_service',
 'C:\\Anaconda2\\python27.zip',
 'C:\\Anaconda2\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib',
 'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\plat-win',
 'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'C:\\Anaconda2',
 'C:\\Users\\Jaimik Jain\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python27\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin',
 'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\pywinpty-0.5-py2.7-win-amd64.egg']
Server time:    Thu, 7 Jun 2018 09:56:44 +0000
```

I request your help at the earliest.

Comment: You should `pop` `submitted_by` before performing a `super().__init__` call.

Comment: I popped the values but, I get this error, "TypeError at /user_dashboard/RepairRequest.html
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'choice' ". What could be the cause? @WillemVanOnsem

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your here pass parameters `submitted_by` and `device_type` to the `RepairForm` constructor. Since you mention those explicitly, it means that those are stored in the `kwargs` dictionary.

You however do *not* modify this dictionary, before performing a `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)` call. As a result, the *superclass* (the `ModelForm`) will receive these parameters as well, but it does *not* understand how to handle those parameters. As a result it will error.

You thus need to remove those parameters from the `kwargs`. For example with `.pop(..)`:

```
class RepairForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        dlist = kwargs.pop("device_type")
        submitted_by = kwargs.pop("submitted_by")
        super(RepairForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["device_type"] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[dlist])
        self.fields["submitted_by"] = submitted_by
```

Youshould also use `choices=...` as parameter when initializing a `ChoiceField`, instead of `choice=...`.

I think there are multiple extra errors, but I hope this provides some good directions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped but, after changing the code, I get this:   ValueError at /user_dashboard/RepairRequest.html
too many values to unpack   @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: @AishwaryShukla: yes you probably should write `choices=dlist`, instead of wrapping it in an extra list.

Comment: It's still the same. @WillemvanOnsem

Comment: @AishwaryShukla: well I would advice you to inspet what `dlist` actually contains. `choices` should be an iterable of 2-tuples: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#field-choices

Comment: What alternatives are present for choicefield? @WillienVanOnsem

Answer (score 1):

What does your Repair model look like?

If field `device_type` is a foreign key to a model that contains your users devices, I think it would be a lot easier to override that fields queryset in your view rather than messing with form init. You could do:

```
form = RepairForm()
form.fields['device_type'].queryset = MyDeviceModel.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

Note there's also no need to be passing submitted_by when calling `RepairForm()` - the field is excluded on the form itself and your already handling populating the `submitted_by` field correctly within your `if form.is_valid()` block so I don't think that's accomplishing anything.

**EDIT**

views.py

```
def repair_form(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RepairForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.submitted_by = request.user
            post.save()
            return redirect("RepairRequest")
    else:
       form = RepairForm()
       form.fields['device_type'].queryset = DeviceType.objects.filter(user=request.user)

       return render(request, "Form_template.html", {"form": form, "name": "Repair Request Form"})
```

forms.py

```
class RepairForm(forms.ModelForm):

   class Meta:
      model = Repair
      exclude = ( "repair_cost_estimate","repair_status","submitted_by","repair_request_date",)
```

Comment: Here MyDeviceModel must be replaced by the model name that exists in my DB right? @WilliamShaw

Comment: Yes, correct, assuming that is how your models are set up - if you like to add your Repair model to your original post I may be able to assist further.

Comment: Updated. @WilliamShaw

Comment: Updated. @WilliamShaw

Comment: @AishwaryShukla I've edited my answer the views and forms that should work for you. Note I also removed the "fields = '__all__' because it's not necessary to call both fields and exclude. Sorry if the formatting/indentation is slightly off, I'm on mobile. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help william but, I got this : FieldError at /user_dashboard/RepairRequest.html
Cannot resolve keyword 'submitted_by' into field. Choices are: device, device_type, id, repair, request  @WilliamShaw

Comment: Try post.submitted_by = request.user.username, since you have to_field=username set on your models definition